# Copy stored procedure from MySQL5.0.5 to MySQL 5.0.1

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I cannot copy stored procedure from MySQL 5.0.5 to MySQL 5.0.1.
Although I can copy all the tables. When I copy stored procedure it gives error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE `insertAccumCursor`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLAR' at line 1
```

the stored procedure on 5.0.51b-community-nt is

```
   CREATE DEFINER=`nobody`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insertAccumCursor`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE userid INT;
  DECLARE counter INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM users WHERE InstitutionID='ReportTest';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  Set counter = 1;
  OPEN cur1;
  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO userid;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
      INSERT INTO myeltaccumgradebook VALUES (counter +12000,0, userid, 'ReportTest', 576389201, 0,1,1,1,1,CEIL(RAND() * 99) +50, '2013-07-10 16:10:54','2013-07-10 16:10:54', 0);
      set counter = counter+1;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

Comment: Try losing the `` around insertAccumCursor, you don't need them when defining a stored procedure

Comment: 5.0.1 was Alpha version, and it possible that procedures were not supported. I'd suggest you to install new and stable version.

Comment: @Devart thanks ... it seems i have no other option

Comment: I understand that you want to copy a stored procedure of MySQL 5.0.51 to 5.0.1, right?. The basic support stored procedure beginning in MySQL 5.0.0, some other clauses as `DEFINER` (added in MySQL 5.0.20) are supported in later version, so maybe not all work correctly. You must set the stored procedure to the specific version you use.

Answer (score 0):

How do you make procedure insert in new DB? With which tool? If you use phpmyadmin I can suggest you to save stored procedure to file and try to import it with cli

Comment: i use sqlyog8.5.5. I installed the mysql 5.0.51b which is the same version as the database i was trying to copy the procedure from. Everything works fine now. I guess @Devart was right.